# Help in defining a custom command when -nargs=? : how to determine if the arg is passed or not in the repl part?

Tags: vimscript

I am struggling with this line (**Vim9script**):

```
command! -nargs=? MyCommand :call <sid>MyFunc(???)
```

What I would like to do is to replace the `???` in the `MyFunc` call in the above example so that I have the following effect:

```
if <f-args>
    :call <sid>MyFunc(readfile(<f-args>))
else
    :call <sid>MyFunc(g:some_defaults)
```

How to do that?

**EDIT:** a partial solution that I found is the following:

```
command! -nargs=? -complete=file MyCommand {
    var items: list<string> 
    if empty(<f-args>)
        items = g:some_defaults
    else
        items = readfile(<f-args>) 
    endif
    MyFunc(items)
}
```

But if I call it without arguments, i.e. `:MyCommand` I get `E119: Not enough arguments for function: empty`

It looks like that the problems boils down in checking if the arg is passed or not during the custom command is invokation, i.e. I don't understand how to discriminate if the command is invoked as `:MyCommand` or `:MyCommand somefile` in my custom command definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:** The solution I found is to check if the arg is passed in the called function

```
def MyFunc(...arg: list<string>)
    if empty(arg)
        echo "No passed arg"
    else
        echo "passed arg"
    endif
enddef

command! -nargs=? MyCommand :call <sid>MyFunc(<f-args>)
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling a function, a default argument can be used to distinguish

```
vim9script
def MyFunc(arg: string = "NOTSET")
    if arg == "NOTSET"
        echo "No passed arg"
    else
        echo "passed arg " .. arg
    endif
enddef

command! -nargs=? MyCommand call <SID>MyFunc(<f-args>)
```

When using inline block command, use `"<args>"`

```
vim9script
command! -nargs=? MyCommand2 {
    if "<args>" == ""
        echo "No passed arg"
    else
        echo "passed arg <args>"
    endif
}
```